# Refresh List Dialog in Android with removeDialog() in onPrepareDialog method

Tags: android

Is it considered bad form to call removeDialog(int) in onPrepareDialog as shown below to force re-creating the dialog every time it is called with showDialog():

```
@Override
public void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) 
{
    switch(id) 
    {
        case REMOVE_WATCH_WORD :
            removeDialog(REMOVE_WATCH_WORD);
            break;

    }
 }
```

and in the onCreateDialog I handle it with this case argument:

```
case REMOVE_WATCH_WORD :
CustomHelper ch = new CustomHelper();
final CharSequence[] watchWordsCharSequence = ch.getWatchWordsAsCharSequence(getApplicationContext());

return new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this)

    .setTitle("Remove Word from List")

    .setItems(watchWordsCharSequence, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\"" + watchWordsCharSequence[item] + "\" removed from List!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String removeString = (String) watchWordsCharSequence[item];
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = watchWords.edit();
            editor.remove(removeString);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }).create();
```

Is it considered bad form to force the dialog to be re-drawn every time it is called?  What are the benefits/disadvantages in doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would consider that bad form.  Does it even work?  `onPrepareDialog()` is called even after the first time you create the dialog, which means you're choosing to **remove** the dialog immediately after **creating** it.  Looks problematic to me.

The whole reason `Activity` exposes the `showDialog()`, `dismissDialog()`, `onCreateDialog()`, `onPrepareDialog()` family of methods is to be able to efficiently manage the Dialog's lifecycle, and specifically so you don't have to manually hold on to references to your dialogs.  The idiomatic lifecycle is you create the Dialog in `onCreateDialog()`, including attaching any event listeners you need.  Then in `onPrepareDialog()` is where you initialize values, things like text, initial values, etc -- or in other words "refreshing" the dialog for an impending display.  There should be no reason to destroy and recreate your dialog between displays.  Instead of using `removeDialog()` to "refresh" it, you should actually look into what it will take to properly refresh the contents.  Usually that would involve something like `.getAdapter().notifyDataSetInvalidated()`, or if using `CursorAdapter`, calling `requery()` to force it to rerun the query and update the adapter contents.

If you **do** find that you still need to remove and recreate the dialog, then I would recommend abandoning the entire `Activity`-managed dialog idiom, and instead create the dialog when you need it and call its `show()` method.  When you're done with it, dismiss and enqueue for GC.  That bypasses the entire show/create/prepare process that Activity exposes.

I would suggest sticking to the Activity-managed dialogs, but not if you're planning to remove the dialog every time -- in that case just instantiate and `.show()`

Comment: Thank you for providing such a detailed response.  Just for arguments sake, I would like to discuss the reasons why I think it's not such a bad idea.  You say that I'm destroying the dialog immediately after creating it, but that is not necessarily true.  If the system calls onPrepareDialog immediately before calling onCreateDialog, doesn't the code above destroy the dialog immediately BEFORE creating it, thus forcing the entire dialog to be re-drawn?  I've edited my original post to show you what I'm doing in onCreateDialog.  Again, not trying to argue, simply looking for input. Thanks

Comment: This is a new project I'm working on, but as far as I can tell this method is working.  I need to populate a new CharSequence array every time this dialog is called.

Comment: @dell116 That's not the case, `Activity#showDialog()` first checks if it already has a managed dialog instance -- if not, it calls `onCreateDialog()`, where your activity has a chance to instantiate and initialize the dialog of its choosing, and saves that dialog instance for later.  Then, whether newly created or already cached, it passes the managed dialog to `onPrepareDialog()`.  The difference is `onCreateDialog()` is called **only once** for a single dialog id, and `onPrepareDialog()` is called on every `showDialog(ID)`. All of the above is for a single id.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of deleting the Dialog is an interesting approach rather than going through the overhead of making a custom adapter for lightweight dynamic lists. At first glance, deleting from within onPrepareDialog() may not be the best approach for most implementations though.

Another approach would be to delete the dialog only when the list's dynamic data is updated.

```
private final int DIALOG_ID = 1;
String mDialogList[] = {"item 1","item 2"};

private void updateListData(){
    mDialogList = new String[]{"new item 1","new item 2"};
    removeDialog(DIALOG_ID);
}
```

Using this approach the dialog will only be reconstructed after underlying data changes, otherwise it should be cached and managed by the Activity as normal.